# how can i pass a DataTable as a parameter from view to backing bean?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable, parameter-passing, exporter

I'm implementing a custom pdf exporter, but i need to pass my datatable from the view to my backing bean, but i dont know how to do it.

in the view i'll have a commandlink that is going to look like this:

```
  <h:commandLink action="#{procesos.exportPDF( mytable , 'procesos')}">
     </h:commandLink>
```

this is the method that receive a DataTable as a parameter:

```
public void exportPDF(DataTable table, String filename) throws IOException {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        Exporter exporter = new CustomPDFExporter();
        exporter.export(context, table, filename, false, false, "iso-8859-1", null, null);
        context.responseComplete();
    }
```

anyway.. what i want to do is to modify column width with a custompdf exporter because dataexporter and the exporter extension of primefaces does not allow that function, so if someone knows or have a custom pdf exporter that allow that it would be much appreciated to show a little bit (better all ) of the code :)!

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem.
I did not pass the table directly. I just passed the ids of the form and the table and used the findComponent

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
UIViewRoot viewRoot = context.getViewRoot();

// find table by form- and table-id
UIComponent component = viewRoot.findComponent(formId).findComponent(tableId);
DataTable table = (DataTable) component;
```